# How can I add multiple conditions in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, show-hide

I have button `Description`. When clicked description is displayed. Now I want to add `Read more/less` on description.

With the belpw code, I do not see button `Description`, description is displayed directly

Flow- Display button-> On click-> Show 200 character text (With Read more option)

```
  const [readMore, setReadMore] = useState(false);


  const [displaydescription, setDisplayDescription] = useState(false);
  const clickHandler = () => {
    setDisplayDescription(true);
  };

 <p>
          {displaydescription || readMore
            ? description
            : `${description.substring(0, 200)}`}
        </p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your code to first display description and then in second condition to verify if you want to show the full text like this:

```js
const [readMore, setReadMore] = useState(false);
const [displaydescription, setDisplayDescription] = useState(false);
const clickHandler = () => {
    setDisplayDescription(true);
};

 <p>
    {displaydescription 
       ? (
            readMore
               ? description
               : `${description.substring(0, 200)
         )
       : null}`
    }
 </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax to add a condition in React jsx is {condition &&  }
so you could try

```
{ description && !readmore 
  <p> `${description.substring(0, 200)}` <p>
}
{ description && readmore 
  <p> `${description}` <p>
}
```